# How to use PySCIPOpt for feasibility-only problem

Tags: feasibility, pyscipopt

I have used CVXPY and some of its LP solvers to determine whether a solution to an A*x <= b problem is feasible, and now I would like to try PySCIPOpt.  I could not find an example of this in the docs, and I'm having trouble figuring out the right syntax.  With CVXPY the code is simply:

```
def do_cvxpy(A, b, solver):
    x = cvxpy.Variable(A.shape[1])
    constraints = [A@x <= b] #The @ denotes matrix multiplication in CVXPY
    obj = cvxpy.Minimize(0)
    prob = cvxpy.Problem(obj, constraints)
    prob.solve(solver=solver)
    return prob.status
```

I think with PySCIPOpt one cannot use matrix notation as above, but must treat vectors and matrices as collections of scalar variables, each of which has to be added individually, so I tried this:

```
def do_scip(A, b):
    model = Model("XYZ")
    x = {}
    for i in range(A.shape[1]):
        x[i] = model.addVar(vtype="C", name="x(%s)" % i)
        
    model.setObjective(0)  #Is this right for a feasibility-only problem?
    model.addCons(A*x <= b) #This is certainly the wrong syntax
    model.optimize()
    return model.getStatus()
```

Could anyone please help me out with the correct form for the constraint in addCons() for this kind of problem, and confirm that an acceptable way to ask whether a solution is feasible is to simply pass 0 as the objective?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not positive about the setObjective(0), but at least I can get the code to run without errors by "unpacking" the `A` matrix and the `b` vector and adding each element as a constraint:

```
for i in range(ncols):
    for j in range(nrows):
        model.addCons(A[j,i]*x[i] <= b[i])
```

I also discovered that CVXPY actually has an interface to SCIP, but it gives me an error when I try to use it:

```
getSolObjVal cannot only be called in stage SOLVING without a valid solution
```

which seems to suggest that the interface cannot be used for feasibility-only problems.